# directory which stores logs has grown to 3.7 GB how can I manage

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, logrotate

I am having this situation the log file /var/log/auth.log on my server has grown very large in size.A lot of webserver are running on it and similar stuff I see the log entries since 15 days have not been recorded. I have been doing an SSH on it from my lan and home the server I am referring is having a public IP but I see that log entries are missing on it from past 12 days in /var/log/auth.log.What can be the reason upon this checked size of the directory which stores logs it is 3.7 GB can this be a problem?

Comment: What does `df -hT` report?

Comment: Based on your comment below & a closer reading of your question I'm wondering if your disk isn't full -- see Steven's comment above: If there's no free space obviously nothing can be logged.  You'll need to go on a cleaning spree before checking log rotation :)

Comment: What I did is copied the log files to some remote location and then deleted the files on server so now I am having 3.7 Gb freed on the server about which I reported the problem.I this what log rotate does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your logs are not being rotated.  I'd wager that `auth.log` is >2GB and your filesystem doesn't support files over that size (so no more data can be written to it).

Check your logrotate configuration to ensure that it knows `auth.log` is supposed to be rotated (with a reasonable timeframe, like every day), and ensure that logrotate is actually running (it's usually part of the daily or hourly cron tasks).

If everything looks good try running logrotate manually (as root) to see if there are any errors.

Comment: It is a Ubuntu server

I checked the size of auth.log is just 72K but size of folder /var/log is 3.7 Gb here are the file sizes 
4.0K    ./apparmor
4.0K    ./news
56K     ./image-store-proxy
4.0K    ./unattended-upgrades
32K     ./ConsoleKit
44K     ./cron-apt
633M    ./eucalyptus
360K    ./installer/cdebconf
1.3M    ./installer
364K    ./apache2/site3
4.0K    ./apache2/site
1.5G    ./apache2/site2
145M    ./apache2/log_20_July
630M    ./apache2/site1
153M    ./apache2/site4
2.4G    ./apache2
12K     ./fsck '

Comment: 4.0K    ./landscape
92K     ./apt
156K    ./libvirt/qemu
160K    ./libvirt
4.0K    ./dist-upgrade
4.0K    ./samba/cores/smbd
4.0K    ./samba/cores/nmbd
12K     ./samba/cores
1.5M    ./samba
3.7G    ./



and why is editing so difficult in comments?

Comment: Your samba directory looks like a problem... in fact, it looks like your problem exactly.